# Changing background Image depending on level in game javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, html

So I'm building a water pipe base game which can be seen here http://www.mckenziedave.co.uk/client_files/gabi_pipes/ 
I thought id post it rather than explain it.

Im using HTML5 and JS script but I have hit a little problem, I wish to change the background depending on what level the user is on. Would this be best done by CSS or could I implement it into the java script? Instead of posting all the scripts I have just posted the level selector and level creator (the game board works on a basis of 0/1).

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    PipeGame.configure({
        cols: 4,
        rows: 6,
        startX:0,
        StartY:0,
        lastX:3,
        lastY:5,
        godMode: true,
        autoStart: null     
    });

    var board =[[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]],
                [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]];

    PipeGame.setGameBoard(board);

    var slider = new Slider($(".options"))

});

var Slider = function(el){
    this.el = el;
    this.dragging = false;
    this.startx = this.el.offset().left;
    this.el.on("touchstart",this.startDrag.bind(this));
    this.el.on("touchmove",this.drag.bind(this));
    this.el.on("touchend",this.stopDrag.bind(this));
}

Slider.prototype.startDrag = function(e){
    this.startx = e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
    this.dragging = true;

}
Slider.prototype.stopDrag = function(e){
    this.dragging = false;
}
Slider.prototype.drag = function(e){

    var pos = Math.round($(".plumbing-creator").position().left - (this.startx - e.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX)  );


    if(this.dragging){

        this.el.css({left:  pos +"px"})
    }
}


var levels = {
    level1: [[["0","1","0","1"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"]],[["0","0","1","1"],["0","1","1","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"]],[["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","1","1"],["1","1","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"]],[["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","1","1"],["1","0","1","0"],["1","0","1","0"],["1","1","0","0"]]],
    level2: [[["0","1","1","0"],["0","1","1","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"]],[["0","0","0","0"],["0","1","1","0"],["0","1","1","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"]],[["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","1","1","0"],["0","1","1","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"]],[["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","0","0","0"],["0","1","1","0"],["0","1","0","1"],["0","1","1","0"]]],
    level3: [[["0","1","0","1"],["0","1","1","0"],["0","0","1","1"],["1","1","0","0"],["0","1","1","0"],["1","1","0","0"]],[["0","1","0","1"],["0","1","0","1"],["0","1","0","1"],["0","1","0","1"],["0","1","0","1"],["0","1","0","1"]],[["0","1","0","1"],["0","1","0","1"],["0","1","0","1"],["0","1","0","1"],["0","1","0","1"],["0","1","0","1"]],[["0","0","1","1"],["1","0","0","1"],["0","0","1","1"],["0","1","0","1"],["1","0","0","1"],["0","1","0","1"]]],
}
```

Anyone know of an easy way to change the background depending on the level?? Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS. 
For each level, you can create a different CSS class.

Example:

```
.level1
{
    background-color: red;
}
.level2
{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a couple ways off the top of my head depending on the rest of your code.

1) When a level changes, set a class on the body.

**JS**

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = 'level-whatever';
```

**CSS**

```
body.level-whatever {
    background: do-what-you-want
}
```

2) Just change the background with JS.

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("whatever-url")';
```

Comment: Hi sorry where would I add 'document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].className = 'level-whatever';?' in the levels js part?

Comment: It's hard to tell without looking at your code but wherever the level is set is where you would want to set the class.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that your `main.js`, which has the following configuration:

```
PipeGame.configure({
  cols: 4,
  rows: 6,
  startX:0,
  StartY:0,
  lastX:3,
  lastY:5,
  godMode: true,
  autoStart: null     
});
```

Is called everytime you visit a different `arcade.html#*` page. You could potentially add another configuration setting:

```
background: level*,
```

And change something based on that. To be honest, this is a pretty broad question with a lot of different ways to accomplish the task at hand. Applying a CSS rules based on your level (like so):

```
var currentLevel = parseInt(window.location.hash.substring(1)) || 1;

if(currentLevel == 1){
  $("body").addClass("last-level");
  $("body").style(...);
} // Use as a Case Statement or have an array of level backgrounds, etc
```

Seems to be the consensus here.